# Deploying MS Teams App to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, office365

I have created a simple Teams App using Yeoman Generator and have added a single static tab to my Teams project. I'm trying to deploy this to an Azure App Service. This is the error log from App Service Deployment Center

```
Failed to load ./.env.
[11:41:54] [Webpack error] multi ./src/app/scripts/client.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\home\site\repository/src/app/scripts/client.ts' in 'D:\home\site\repository'
resolve 'D:\home\site\repository/src/app/scripts/client.ts' in 'D:\home\site\repository'
Unhandled rejection [31mError[39m in plugin "[36mwebpack[39m"
  using description file: D:\home\site\repository\package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: D:\home\site\repository\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/scripts/client.ts)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Message:
    Webpack errors, see log
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts.tsx doesn't exist
Unhandled rejection [31mError[39m in plugin "[36mwebpack[39m"
Message:
    Webpack errors, see log
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts doesn't exist
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts]
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts.ts]
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts.tsx]
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\scripts\client.ts.js]
 @ multi ./src/app/scripts/client.ts client[0]
[11:41:55] [Webpack error] multi ./src/app/server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\home\site\repository/src/app/server.ts' in 'D:\home\site\repository'
resolve 'D:\home\site\repository/src/app/server.ts' in 'D:\home\site\repository'
  using description file: D:\home\site\repository\package.json (relative path: .)
    using description file: D:\home\site\repository\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/server.ts)
      no extension
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts doesn't exist
      .ts
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts.tsx doesn't exist
      .js
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts doesn't exist
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts]
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts.ts]
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts.tsx]
[D:\home\site\repository\src\app\server.ts.js]
 @ multi ./src/app/server.ts server[0]
[tslint-plugin] Starting linter in separate process...
[tslint-plugin] Starting linter in separate process...
[tslint-plugin] Linting complete.
[tslint-plugin] Linting complete.
[11:42:02] The following tasks did not complete: build, webpack, webpack:client, webpack:server
[11:42:02] Did you forget to signal async completion?
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! emphub@0.0.1 build: `gulp build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the emphub@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is my webpack.config.js file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
var TSLintPlugin = require('tslint-webpack-plugin');

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;

var debug = argv.debug !== undefined;
const lint = argv["linting"];

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function (x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function (mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

var config = [{
        entry: {
            server: [
                __dirname + '/src/app/server.ts'
            ],
        },
        mode: debug ? 'development' : 'production',
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: '[name].js',
            devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: debug ? '[absolute-resource-path]' : '[]'
        },
        externals: nodeModules,
        devtool: 'source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
            alias: {}
        },
        target: 'node',
        node: {
            __dirname: false,
            __filename: false,
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: [/lib/, /dist/],
                loader: "ts-loader"
            }]
        },
        plugins: []
    },
    {
        entry: {
            client: [
                __dirname + '/src/app/scripts/client.ts'
            ]
        },
        mode: debug ? 'development' : 'production',
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist/web/scripts',
            filename: '[name].js',
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            library: 'emphub',
            publicPath: '/scripts/'
        },
        externals: {},
        devtool: 'source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
            alias: {}
        },
        target: 'web',
        module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    exclude: [/lib/, /dist/],
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    options: {
                        configFile: "tsconfig-client.json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new Dotenv({
                systemvars: true
            })
        ],
        performance: {
            maxEntrypointSize: 400000,
            maxAssetSize: 400000,
            assetFilter: function(assetFilename) {
                return assetFilename.endsWith('.js');
              }
        }
    }
];

if (lint !== false) {
    config[0].plugins.push(new TSLintPlugin({
        files: ['./src/app/*.ts']
    }));
    config[1].plugins.push(new TSLintPlugin({
        files: ['./src/app/scripts/**/*.ts', './src/app/scripts/**/*.tsx']
    }));
}


module.exports = config;
```

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong? I'm pusing the code using git push azure master from my project root directory

Comment: Can Anybody help me with the above question?